# how to express y(t) as function of x(t) from a given two signal?

Tags: math, graph

[image]

is there a simple way to answer ?
I couldn't do it by finding the equation of the two signal and then proceed like any problem in math

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a quiz about transformation. We don't do homework problems here, but I'll try to explain how this problem works. All of the choices have

$$
y(t) = -x(-2t + toffset) + 1.5
$$

Where Toffset is 0, +2, -2, -1, or something else. So first look at the transformations that are common to all of the choices, and understand what each of them does. Try to visualize what the graph should look like.

Adding a constant offset should shift everything up:

$$
    y(t) = x(t) + 1.5
$$

Multiplying the x(t) by -1 is a verical flip:

$$
    y(t) = -x(t)
$$

Multiplying the x argument by 2 makes time go faster:

$$
    y(t) = x(2t)
$$

Multiplying the x() argument by -2 makes time go faster, but backwards:

$$
    y(t) = x(-2t)
$$

And now just adding an offset to the x() argument shifts when time 0 starts.

$$
    y(t) = x(t+toffset)
$$

Note that the graph of x(t) has a convenient, distinct feature at time 0, so it helps if you can find where that feature is on the y(t) graph that you're trying to match.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by looking at the shape of the x(t) graph, then looking for similar shapes in the y(t) graph. Each one has a triangular part and a trapezoidal part. You have to make them line up. Doing that takes four things:

- Inverting the y axis (a form of scaling)
- Scaling the x axis
- Shifting the x axis
- Shifting the y axis

You can figure out the numerical values for each part by looking at the graph. For example, the y intercept point (corner of the triangle) moves two units over, so your equation should have x(… - 2) in it somewhere.